# How to Create Badge Count Label in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

In my game, need to show badge count to show number score, like the one in attached image.

[image: Badge Lable like in the image]

Comment: There is no question here ...

Comment: use cc.LabelTTF and setString method

Answer (score 0):

`cc.LabelTTF` alone can't do the trick, here is a brief solution:

First, the background image of the badge is formed by 3 pictures:

Half circle on the left, half circle on the right and rectangle on the center.

2 half circles are premade and attached to both side of the badge. Use a `cc.LabelTTF` to show numbers, you also need to get width and height of label to scale rectangle image to a proper size.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, can't I go with adding color layer or same size and giving border to it and add label in it?